# Term to describe generalizations such as "it is well known"

Tags: phrases, writing-style

Is there a term to describe phrases such as:
"it is well known that,"
"most people believe that," or
"it is often thought that?"

I see these phrases used when someone tries to present their opinion as an accepted fact even when their argument is not supported by fact.

Comment: Channel markers for stuff that should be checked before being accepted?

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia calls them "weasel words", which is as good a term as any. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word for a good description.

Comment: Possibly, but 'weasel words' is used rather more widely.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually a logical fallacy called ["appeal to the majority"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum).  Fallacious is a good description, although I like weasel words and unsubstantiated generalizations as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your question describes the phrases very well: generalizations.
An opinion not backed up by fact is an [unsubstantiation](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=unsubstantiation&pbx=1&oq=unsubstantiation&aq=f&aqi=g-s4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=12978l13208l10l14798l2l2l0l0l0l1l716l1230l5-1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2394b8aec80a8ebc&biw=1280&bih=713). *"His arguments are full of unsubstatiations."*

Answer (score 1):

I've seen "deadwood phrases" used to discribe such phrases that add nothing to the meaning  and could (and should) be removed (like dead wood) from the sentence. Although I would suggest that "It is often thought that" isn't necessarily one such phrase as it indicates that a contrary opinion is going to be asserted. As in "It is often thought that Picasso was French, although he was Spanish" - the phrase adds something to the sentence beyond simply stating: "Picasso was Spanish".

Answer (score 0):

These phrases are all similar in that they might be used to persuade someone through the false reasoning that if a majority believe something or hold it to be true, that thing must therefore be credible or true.

[Andrew](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45110/term-to-describe-generalizations-such-as-it-is-well-known/45144#45144) is right; this is a logical fallacy. As for a name, I like "[bandwagon fallacy](http://www.fallacyfiles.org/bandwagn.html)".

Answer (score 0):

I would call them *bold statements* or *sweeping generalisations*.

Answer (score 0):

I would characterize such generalizations as **trite**.